# How to set path custom path for cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to set path custom path for cookies

Comment: Can you please give use more details, be polite etc... I know we need all the boring stuff, it's just like that we are sure we are not speaking to machine.

Comment: Wow, I'm a prolific downvoter but I think this is a perfectly fine question.  Odd to get -5 when nonsense I downvote ends up being upvoted just for being downvoted ( users admit to it ).

Answer (score 4):

Just set `HttpCookie.Path` property.

```
public HttpCookie CreateCookie(string name, string value, string path)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);

    cookie.Path = path;

    return cookie;
}
```